# jQuery, No Conflict for Tampermonkey

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I'm toying with a Tampermonkey script for a site that uses an old version of jQuery. I would like to use a more recent version in my script. I have tried this:

```
var contentIndex = 0;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var jQuery_310 = $.noConflict(true);
```

but the `noConflict` runs late (it seems): the site I'm tampering with is now talking to the newer jQuery.

How can I avoid this conflict on the existing site?

Comment: Why not just use the `@require` parameter in the TamperMonkey header? eg `@require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`. https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_require

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that *is* the smartest way for many reasons, but one needs to also specify a `@grant` value other than `none` to avoid jQuery conflicts. (And this uses 2 lines of code versus the monstrosities below.)  Note that such a `@grant` is best practice in most scenarios anyway, because of the extra sandbox protection.

Comment: Re: "is there a way to have both?". Yes, and it has been covered in other GM/TM answers.  Sorry I didn't write an official answer but (1) You've already found something that works for you, (2) everything stated has already been covered in other answers -- but maybe not an exact duplicate, (3) I don't have the time nor inclination to hunt for dupes or write a proper answer right now, (4) This is an X-Y problem with requirements not stated in the Q (see your comment); those always take iterations to satisfy the OP or even touch on the real requirements (See the accepted answer and OP's answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to Tampermonkey:

```
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
```

### Resolving jQuery Conflicts

The main site's use of `$` would refer to the new jQuery (310), which might break things on the "tampered" site. To resolve this, the first line of code could be:

```
window.jQuery310 = $.noConflict(true);
```

**Another option:** [A more restrictive `@grant`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant) would obviate the need for the `noConflict` line.

Comment: How does a more restrictive grant help? You linked to a document that doesn't describe how to do what you say.

Answer (score 3):

Use a load handler on new script tag

```
var jQuery_310; 
script.onload = function() {
  jQuery_310 = $.noConflict(true);
  console.log("$ calls: " + $.fn.jquery + ", jQuery_310 calls: " + jQuery_310.fn.jquery);
  // initialize any code that uses jQuery_310 here
  init_jQuery_310_code(jQuery_310);
}

function init_jQuery_310_code($) {
  console.log("here in init_jQuery_310_code: $ calls: " + $.fn.jquery);     
  // "$" refers to jQuery_310 version here
  // insert code that requires jQuery_310 here, but use "$" instead
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b75w7njy/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. Just for my own records, this literally goes right below the `appendChild` line. Works perfectly.

Comment: can go anywhere after `script` is defined. Order of setting properties not important

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my ignorance, but regarding scoping: how can I get access to the `jQuery_310` elsewhere? If I put the `var jQuery_310;` outside the `script.onload`... it doesn't seem to help. Thanks

Comment: Will need to wrap all your code that references `jQuery_310` in a function and call that function also inside the `onload` callback

Comment: Thanks. Confusingly the method that does the work (thatFunction) is called from `$(window).bind("load hashchange", thatFunction);` .. I've tried a few things, but `thatFunction` can never see `jQuery_310`.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused: moving the thing to global scope was sufficient. You can even do this inside methods: `var $ = jQuery_310;`. Thanks!